# How to send data inside an object and JSON data from postman

Tags: node.js, postman

My Json structure in postman is as below

```
{
    "user":{
    "email":"bangole@gmail.com",
    "password":"bangole@gmail.com",
    "active":true,
    "role_id":"2"
    }
    ,
    "userDetails":{
    "user_name":"bangole"
    }

}
```

so from my code am fetching data like `data.user` or `data.userDetails`

```
var data = req.body;
if(!data.user.email || !data.userDetails.user_name){
return res.status(401).send({
            status: 401,
            data: "Email, Password,  Active and role_id are required fields"
        })
```

this works fine if i post the data in JSON structure like i mentioned above but if i try to post empty json or any invalid input through postman then i will get this error :

> Error: Cannot find module 'html&#39
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)

So how can i solve this issue?

Comment: why did you mention postman...do you meant to validate the response in postman ??????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try with more verifications like this ?

```
var data = req.body;
if (!data || !data.user || !data.user.email || !data.userDetails || !data.userDetails.user_name) {
    return res.status(401).send({
        status: 401,
        data: "Email, Password,  Active and role_id are required fields"
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good to know :)